# Suppose $g$ is a continuous function such that the integral $\int_0^\infty|g(t)|dt$ converges

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, analyticity

Suppose $g$ is a continuous function such that the integral $\int_0^\infty|g(t)|dt$ converges. 
Is $$F(z)=\int_0^\infty g(t)\sin(zt)dt$$
analytic? And if so, in what region?

My attempt:
$$F(z)=\int_0^\infty g(t)\sin(zt)dt=\int_0^\infty g(t)\frac{e^{izt}-e^{-izt}}{2i}dt$$
$$=\int_0^\infty g(t)\frac{e^{izt}}{2i}dt-\int_0^\infty g(t)\frac{e^{-izt}}{2i}dt$$
This is equivalent to 
$$\frac{\mathcal{L}[g(t)](iz)}{2i}-\frac{\mathcal{L}[g(t)](-iz)}{2i},$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Laplace transform.
Since $g$ is continuous and convergent, the Laplace transform is analytic where $Re(iz)>0$ and $Re(-iz)>0$,
which is impossible, so $F(z)$ is not analytic. Is this correct?

Comment: to prove that $F(s)$ is real analytic on some given line of the complex plane, you need to show that $\frac{\partial^k F}{\partial s^k}$ exists (in the real sense) for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ everywhere on the line, or you need to show that in the neighborhood of the line, there is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ where $F(s)$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial s}$ exists (in the complex sense) and then you can apply the holomorphic $\implies$ analytic theorem.

Comment: the problem here is that $\int_0^\infty |g(t)|dt < \infty$ only means that $G(s) = \int_0^\infty g(t) e^{-st}dt$ is analytic on $Re(s) > 0$, but it says nothing of the existence of $\frac{\partial^k G}{\partial s^k} = \int_0^\infty g(t) (-t)^k e^{-st} dt$ on the line $Re(s) = 0$

Comment: and if $g(t)$ has a compact support $[0;a]$, then $G(s) = \int_0^a g(t) e^{-st} dt$ is analytic everywhere (it is an entire function) as $F(s) =\frac{G(-is)-G(is)}{2i}$

Comment: You have omitted some $t$'s in your second displayed equation.

Comment: @user1952009 does this mean I have to calculate $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_0^\infty g(t)\sin((z+h)t)dt-\int_0^\infty g(t)\sin(zt)dt}{h}$?

Comment: @Matt : where it converges, $F(s)$ will be (real) differentiable... no you need to show that all the derivatives exist, i.e. that $\int_0^\infty g(t) t^{2k} \sin(zt) dt$ converges for every $k$ on $Re(z) = 0$.  as I wrote, the alternative is to show that $\int_0^\infty g(t) t \cos(zt) dt$ converges in the neighborhood of $Re(z) = 0$.

Comment: Why is it $\int_0^\infty g(t)t^{2k}\sin(zt)dt$ and not $\int_0^\infty g(t)(-t)^{k}\sin(zt)dt$?